# R: strsplit on negative lookaround

Tags: r, regex-lookarounds, strsplit

Say I need to strsplit `caabacb` into individual letters except when a letter is followed by a `b`, thus resulting in `"c"  "a"  "ab"  "a"  "cb"`. I tried using the following line, which looks OK on regex tester but does not work in R. What did I do wrong?

```
strsplit('caabacb','(?!b)',perl=TRUE)
[[1]]
[1] "c" "a" "a" "b" "a" "c" "b"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also add a prefix positive lookbehind that matches any character `(?<=.)`. The positive lookbehind `(?<=.)` would split the string at every character (without removal of characters), but the negative lookahead `(?!b)` excludes splits where a character is followed by a `b`:

```r
strsplit('caabacb', '(?<=.)(?!b)', perl = TRUE)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "c"  "a"  "ab" "a"  "cb"
```

Comment: Neat solution @JorisChau!

Answer (score 3):

`strsplit()` probably needs something to split. You could insert e.g. a `";"` with `gsub()`.

```
strsplit(gsub("(?!^.|b|\\b)", ";", "caabacb", perl=TRUE), ";", perl=TRUE)
# [[1]]
# [1] "c"  "a"  "ab" "a"  "cb"
```